# AAD thick client auto-login

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, adfs, thick-client

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered many times, but I can't seem to find a good solution.

We have an intranet web site, including a number of web services, that are secured using Azure Active Directory (AAD) and Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS).  When a user, using a thin client (IE or Chrome), accesses the site, authentication happens essentially automatically:  the user can observe URLs changing, but the user's domain account gets passed through and authenticated automatically.  There is no popup and no login process.  After that, the JavaScript in the site has a security context and can access the web services just fine.

Now we want to add a thick client for some of the administrative utilities.  However, I have not found a good way to authenticate the thick client.  As I said, I'm confident this is a common scenario, but I would like my WPF application to behave the way the web browsers do:  use the domain account information and pass it through transparently for authentication.  In fact, I assume there's a NuGet package that does this, but again, I haven't been able to find it.

Any/all help much appreciated.

Thanks!
Brad.

Comment: Good question, have you tried using ADAL or MSAL in the WPF client?

Comment: I think I'm getting close using the "Microsoft.Identity.Client" NuGet package (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet), but I've run up against IT problems.  I need them either to edit the app's manifest to set "allowPublicClient" to true so that I can use the PublicClientApplication's "AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuthAsync" or to supply me with the "client secret" so that I can use the ConfidentialClientApplication's "AcquireTokenForClientAsync".  If I remember, I'll post here again if/when I've got it working and how I did it.

Comment: Do not use a client secret from a native app. It is a public client.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the browser is set to use IWA / WIA (Integrated Windows Auth).

This is browser functionality; not part of ADFS or AAD.

So this can't be implemented by an application (in terms of not being a browser).

There may be some library that does this - I'm not aware of one.

Comment: Well, that gives me a little more information so that I can ask the question more intelligently (thanks for that! :), but otherwise doesn't get me much closer to the solution.  :(

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that's the case.  When I open the site in a browser, I see it getting redirected first to our company's ADFS site and then to a Microsoft login page.  That all happens automatically in a browser.  Why can't I emulate that in my WPF application?